# How to create a large 2-dimensional array with C

Tags: c

I want to have a large 2 dimensional array such like

```
int myArray[10000][2];
```

I was told that the array built in such way is not appropriate, and should use malloc to build in heap. Could someone show me how to accomplish this? thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring a 2-dimensional array of unknown size, C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089731/declaring-a-2-dimensional-array-of-unknown-size-c)

Comment: Duplicate of [c-malloc-for-two-dimensional-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970698/c-malloc-for-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: You may want to have a look at [comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 6.16: How can I dynamically allocate a multidimensional array?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

**//alloc**

```
int **vv = malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   vv[i] = malloc(10000 * sizeof(int));
```

**//free**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    free(vv[i]);
free(vv);
```

Comment: Hi jace, thanks. So should the array be referred as vv or vv2? because you have *vv2, then vv[i].   And it's vv, could I used vv[0][0] to refer to the first slot then? Thanks

Comment: addresses range: vv[0][0] - vv[1][9999] are valid