# Declaring 2d array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, new-operator

Hey so I want to declare an 2d array in one of my classes - it is first declared outside of any methods, and then set size by constructor

```
class xxx
int **triangle;


constructor(int n){
    triangle = new int *[n+1];
    for(int i=0;i<=n; i++) triangle[i]=new int[i+1];
}
```

but the first line of constructor does not work:

```
 error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int**’ to ‘int* [0]’
```

NVM it's fixed - I put int *triangle[]; in my header file.. 40 minutes wasted :D

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007117/how-to-create-a-large-2-dimensional-array-with-c/10007161

Comment: It is not what I want - I want to use new. Also it doesn't work aswell:  error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘void*’ to ‘int* [0]’

Comment: Your code is working for me:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b52e994c4047dfd

Comment: BTW, `std::vector` is better than raw pointer.

Comment: which compiler are you using..

Comment: `std::vector< std::vector<int> >` is better...

Answer (score 3):

```
int constructor(int n)
{
    int** triangle = new int*[n + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
        triangle[i] = new int[i + 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate Solution**

Declaring **2D** array using **std::vector** instead of raw pointer

**n x n matrix:**

```
 std::vector<std::vector<int> >  triangle( n, std::vector<int>(n, 0) );
```

**row x col matrix**

```
 std::vector<std::vector<int> >  triangle( row, std::vector<int>(col, 0) );
```

Note: Both the 2d arrays using std::vector are initialized by 0.